# General sum form for product of sums

Tags: linear-algebra, power-series

Is this possible to write as only with summation notations such as $\sum\sum\cdots$?

$$\prod_{l=1}^{L}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}f_l(x_n)\right)$$

I am not sure if the multinomial expansion would help. As I know that it can be easily used for $\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}f_l(x_n)\right)^L$. However I have different $f_l(\cdot)$ functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can always ditch the product in favor of subscripts on subscripts, this doesn't actually change the equation except alter the notation a bit, but maybe that's what you're looking for.
$$
\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}f_{l_1}(x_n)\right) \cdot
\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}f_{l_2}(x_n)\right) \cdots
\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}f_{l_L}(x_n)\right)
$$
Which you could try and bring all of the sigma's together at the front, but I think it might look messier that way.